# Calculator won't start

Tags: 18.10, gnome-calculator

I'm running 18.10 and recently gnome-calculator stopped functioning. Running it from the command line gives the following results:

```
jr@Ubuntu-HP:~$ gnome-calculator 
You need to connect this snap to the gnome platform snap.

You can do this with those commands:
snap install gnome-3-26-1604
snap connect gnome-calculator:gnome-3-26-1604 gnome-3-26-1604

(the '3-26-1604' number defines the platform version and might change)
```

So, following those instructions:

```
jr@Ubuntu-HP:~$ snap install gnome-3-26-1604
snap "gnome-3-26-1604" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
jr@Ubuntu-HP:~$ snap connect gnome-calculator:gnome-3-26-1604 gnome-3-26-1604
error: snap "gnome-calculator" has no plug named "gnome-3-26-1604"


jr@Ubuntu-HP:~$ apt-cache policy gnome-calculator
gnome-calculator: 
   Installed: (none) 
   Candidate: 1:3.30.1-1ubuntu1 
   Version table:
      1:3.30.1-1ubuntu1 500
      500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Here's my `$PATH`:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Please add output of `snap list` and `apt-cache policy gnome-calculator` to the question.

Comment: Output of snap list is too long for comment. See here: https://pastebin.com/rG3xw0Vw

Comment: ```jr@Ubuntu-HP:~$ apt-cache policy gnome-calculator
gnome-calculator:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.30.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:3.30.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to fix this, would be to use the 'apt' version of gnome-calculator instead of the 'snap' version:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
```

will remove the snap version of the calculator, and the 'apt' version is already installed on your system.  Just open the activities....

Comment: After doing that I get: bash: /snap/bin/gnome-calculator: No such file or directory

Comment: @Jhanarato Could you do `echo $PATH` and add that you your original question?

Comment: Sure, have done.

Comment: @Jhanarato Were there error messages when processing `sudo snap remove gnome-calculator`?  It would be a little odd, but you may need to reboot to clear some cache of files.

Comment: Nope, just `gnome-calculator removed`

Comment: @Jhanarato OK - can you get the output of `which gnome-calculator`

Comment: OK, so a reboot solved the problem. Much obliged!

Answer (score 3):

I found that installing the calculator app via apt instead of snap (the default in 18.04).

Since the issue happened in both your laptop and desktop, it may be due to automatic update of the snap version of gnome-calculator. Use the following command to shift to the apt version.

`sudo snap remove gnome-calculator && sudo apt install gnome-calculator`